# Alternate Tightvnc configuration Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, xfce, vnc

I tried installing tightvnc server using https://serverspace.io/support/help/install-tightvnc-server-on-ubuntu-20-04/

The log file says there is an active X-server already running so the xfce4 does not start (I think).
This also causes tightvnc to use port 5902.
Connecting vnc viewer to 5902 gives me a grey screen. I guess because no xfce.

The runing xserver On 5901 is listed as gnome-shell.
Connecting vnc viewer to 5901 gets connection refused by host.

I think I saw somewhere that the ubuntu desktop uses gnome-shell but don't know.
Can I disable the gnome-shell thing? I don't know where is gets started.
If it's required how to change startup configuration to coexist?

Log File
21/07/23 00:36:06 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
21/07/23 00:36:06 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
21/07/23 00:36:06 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
21/07/23 00:36:06 All Rights Reserved.
21/07/23 00:36:06 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
21/07/23 00:36:06 Desktop name 'X' (steve-Z790-AORUS-ELITE-AX:2)
21/07/23 00:36:06 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
21/07/23 00:36:06 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5902
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
xrdb: No such file or directory
xrdb: can't open file '/home/steve/.Xresources'
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :2
xfce4-session: Another session manager is already running